# How to cast a forwarded parameter pack?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, variadic-functions

I'm replacing a `printf(/*heterogenous pack of arguments*/)` by `LogMessage(/*arguments*/)`.

However, I'm getting

> Error C2665   'swprintf_s': none of the 2 overloads could convert all
>   the argument types

```
template<class ...T>
auto DwarfCuda::LogMessage(T&&... args) -> void
{
    wchar_t updatedMessage[256];
    swprintf_s(updatedMessage, forward<T>(args)...); //C2665
    if (LogMessageChangedCallback != nullptr)
        LogMessageChangedCallback(updatedMessage);
}
```

It works for many examples but not with this one:

```
LogMessage( " GPU Max Clock rate: %.0f MHz (%0.2f GHz)\n",
    deviceProp.clockRate * 1e-3f, deviceProp.clockRate * 1e-6f);
```

Why can't this work (shouldn't the cast happen in the first place) ? How to do this correctly ?

Comment: What do you expect `args` to be? I'm not familiar with `swprintf_s` and if [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sprintf-s-sprintf-s-l-swprintf-s-swprintf-s-l?view=vs-2017) is what you're using, it looks like you need to be passing a buffer size and format string.

Comment: Perhaps you could use `DwarfCuda::LogMessage(const char* format, T&&... args){`
in addition to `swprintf_s(updated_message, 256, format, forward<T>(args)...);` to make the `LogMessage` interface clearer.

Comment: `args` would be `format wchat_t[size], args_pack`, and the format argument is variable eg., `"some text %s"`, `"%d %d"`, `"%d %d %d"`

Comment: Then it appears that you're missing the `sizeOfBuffer` argument between `updatedMessage` and `forward<T>(args)...`, assuming that the documentation I linked is the same function you're using.

Comment: I'm using the other overload.

Comment: [I can't reproduce the error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f511507d78e3067). I was unable to use `swprintf_s` on the online compiler but `swprintf` should behave identically, assuming no funny business. (note that I passed the size explicitly)

Comment: Please show how you are calling the function

Comment: @NathanOliver It's really like a printf call, except with wide strings. (L"")

Comment: Seems to compile [just fine](https://godbolt.org/z/efNXvr) for me.  Without a [mcve] or at least the complete compiler output, I doubt there's much anyone will be able to do but speculate.  I will say that using `std::forward` at all here leads me to think maybe you're trying to use objects that the `printf`-family can't deal with.  It's a C function, so it's limited to numeric types and C-style strings, neither of which benefit from move semantics or perfect forwarding.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Thanks for your insights. You were right, there is a certain call that messes up the function. I updated the question with a non-working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the call of `LogMessage`: the format string must be a `wstring`, hence the absence of `L` in `L" GPU Max Clock rate: %.0f MHz (%0.2f GHz)\n"` triggered the bug.